# How to compute a product of logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, problem-solving, products

I've been reading through Stewart's Calculus textbook, and came across the following problem fairly early on -

> What is $$\prod_{i = 2}^{31} \log_i (i + 1)\;?$$

I did some searching, and found that the answer is 5, but I have absolutely no idea how that was found. There may be something to do with induction that is used because of the context of the problem in the book, though I think that the solution may have more to do with the nature of logarithms themselves.

If anyone has any ideas/solutions, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\log_i(i+1)=\frac{\ln (i+1)}{\ln (i) } \,.$$

Your product is the telescopic...